# Is this a good architecture / design concept for handling/manipulating file uploads?

Tags: architecture, file-upload, queue, msmq

I'm looking at adding multi-file uploading to our `ASP.NET MVC` web application. I am going to use the [3rd Party Multi-File uploader Aurigma](http://www.aurigma.com/) to handle the actual uploading.

Once each file is 100% received by the web server, it needs to be checked for the following

1. is it an image or video.
2. if it's an image, does it need to be resized? if so, resize.
3. if it's a video, we need to re-encode it to flash (unfortunately.. bring on html5 :) )
4. finally, store on S3 amazon.

So i know how to do most of steps 1 to 4 - that's not the question.

My question is: **how should I really be handling this workflow**? Especially if i get a bulk of media at once -> after all, this is a *multi-file* uploader :) I don't want to have lots of media getting processed at once (eg. 5 video's getting encoded to flash..).

So I thought i might have `MSMQ` installed and when each file gets 100% recieved, then pop it into `MSMQ`. That way, only one item is getting *processed* at once. The cost of this, is that if there's a lot of *expensive* processing, the queue might actually start to get a few items in there ... and there will be some waiting period from the time an item is uploaded to the site, until it's actually 100% processed. We can easily handle this in the UI to tell them it's not finished yet.

So - does this sound like an OK way to handle this problem?

Secondly, this is in a web farm scenario .. so installation / deployment / maintenance needs to be considered.

Would love to see what other people are thinking.

Answer (score 1):

I like your solution.

The MVC layer should be responsible for validating the file and queueing the request only.  A background process should do the encoding and other heavy lifting.

With this architecture you gain the ability to have multiple encoding servers if that's where the bottleneck ends up.

I've used MSMQ in the past in similar situations.  It's a great "fire and forget" solution, particularly across server boundaries.  Obviously you could use web services, shared file system, etc. for the UI -> background processing communication, but I think MSMQ is the right answer.

Comment: Cheers :) I'm hoping someone might also extend this discussion into a suggesting an MSQM cloud solution .. if that exists and if that's appropriate in this scenario ???

Answer (score 0):

What about running a windows service that watches temp directory (the directory that the files are uploaded).  Then have it spawn X threads of simultaneous processing.  That way if you set X to 10, then it will only process 10 files at a time. Once processed, they can be moved to the permanent directory and the service will pick up the next file in the temp directory.

It keeps the processing out of your web application too.

Comment: I must admin, that is what i _currently_ have -> a file watcher in a Windows Service. But it's a support and maintenance nightmare. And the threading is also a pain which MSMQ can alieviate IMO. Why save it to a temp location and then watch that location, and what happens if we have more files queued, etc? MSQM does all that for you. But yeah.. your idea is something I'm after -> idea's to solving this problem :) cheers!

Comment: I would advise against using MSMQ as a temporary storage medium. Save the file to a temp dir and submit a queue message with the  location of the file - do not store the file itself in MSMQ.